# Get all possible pairs from multiple large lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, large-data

I have a large dict: 600 keys with items = big list (about 10000-20000 elements).

My goal is to get pairs from each list in dict and merge it in one list.

E.g. i have:

```
d1 = {'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'key2': ['f', 'a']}
```

Expected result:

```
d2 = ['a_b', 'a_c', 'a_d', 'b_c', 'b_d', 'c_d', 'a_f']
```

My code:

```
d2 = [] 
for k, v in d1.items():
    for i, j in itertools.product(v, v):
        if i>j:
            a = "_".join(list(set([i, j])))
            d2.append(a)
```

And I have a problem: in terminal my python script says 'Killed'.

This is probably due to inappropriate memory usage. Are there ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is **not a `product`, but `combinations`**.

Furthermore **if memory is an issue, you better use a generator** so:

```
from itertools import combinations

def dic_comb_generator(d1):
    for v in d1.values():
        for t in combinations(sorted(v),2):
            yield "%s_%s"%t
```

Here we use `sorted(..)` to first sort the elements in `v` such that the resulting tuples are sorted as well. In case you do *not* want the combinations to be sorted, but occur in the order of the list, you should remove the `sorted(..)` function. Furthermore we use `2` since we construct combinations (tuples) with two elements.

If we materialize the output, we get:

```
>>> list(dic_comb_generator({'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'key2': ['f', 'a']}))
['a_b', 'a_c', 'a_d', 'b_c', 'b_d', 'c_d', 'a_f']
```

But if you use the generator in a `for` loop, like:

```
for elem in dic_comb_generator(d1):
    print(elem)
```

Python will **not construct a list with all elements**: all elements will be generated, but if you do not store them, then the memory used for the first item emitted, can be *reused* for the second item. Especially in the context of products, combinations,... where the number of elements can be huge, this can pay off: storing a list of 100M+ results in a huge memory burden, whereas handling one element at the time has constant memory usage.

Comment: thanks a lot! And how can I apply Counter to generator?

Comment: @uzver: simply `Counter(dic_comb_generator(d1))`.

Comment: @uzver: then the number of *different* elements is too much. You will have to count them in aother way.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
import itertools as it
for l in d1.values():
    for t in it.combinations(sorted(l), 2):
        print("_".join(t))
```

Displaying:

```
a_b
a_c
a_d
b_c
b_d
c_d
a_f
```

Note: If you do not want it to be sorted, simply take out the `sorted`  function call.

Comment: What if OP doesn't want it sorted like that? a, b, c, d is just a representative example, but what if the input is w, g, k, l?

Comment: @Coldspeed In his example code there was an `if i>j` clause causing me to think he wanted it to be sorted. But I will add a note about that. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generator that doesn't involve `itertools`:

```
def dic_comb_generator(d):
    for val in d.values():
        v = sorted(val)
        for i in range(len(v)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(v)):
                yield v[i] + '_' + v[j]
```